# How to stop JButton being enabled when mouse hovers over it?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I created a frame using NetBeans. The frame has two buttons A and B. Button A is initially disabled. It is to be enabled only when button B is clicked.

```
public newFrame() {    //newFrame is the name of the frame that has buttons A&B
    initComponents();

    btn_A.disable();
}

    private void btn_BActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    btn_A.enable();
}
```

The problem is that button A becomes active/enabled when the mouse is moved over it ie inspite of whether button B is clicked or not. How can i fix this?

I want button A to be enabled only after button B is clicked and not as a result of any other event.

Comment: where is button B, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, just about two JButtons

Comment: button B is on the same frame as button A.

Comment: `button B is on the same frame as button A.` up to you, then all answers here answering your question

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `btn_A.setEnabled(false)` instead of `btn_A.disable()`

Answer (score 1):

`btn_A.enable()` is a deprecated method.
To do this task, you could replace it by `btn_A.setEnabled(false);` to disable the button and `btn_A.setEnabled(true);` to enable the button.

Also, one more suggestion is, add statements like the following in your method if you feel something wrong happening:

```
    System.out.println("Some statement relevant to the method");
```

The main aim of those extra statements being you know when the method was actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
button. addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) { 
            button.setEnable(true); 
      } 

      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) { 
           button.setEnable(false); 
      } 

    });
```

Comment: How will this help ? S/He has a clear requirement: button A should be disabled until button B is clicked. When a button is clicked you get a decent event (ActionEvent) which you can intercept with an ActionListener. Why would you want to opt for a mouse listener